# embedded video from folder disappearing inconsistently

Tags: html, video, hta

I have an embedded video in a HTA application like this:

`<embed src="videos/StartTestSmall.mp4" width="660" height="400" type="video/mp4" autoplay="0" />`

The problem with it is when I load the HTA application sometimes the video shows up and sometimes it does not. If anyone has any information this it would be much appreciated. if any more information is needed let me know. Thank you.

EDIT:

Here is the code:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" >
 <head>
  <!--<meta http-equiv="x-ua-compatible" content="ie=11">-->
  
  <meta http-equiv="Content-type" content="text/html;charset=UTF-8" />
  
  <title>Welcome!</title>
  <!--<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/reset.css"type="text/css" />-->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/960.css" type="text/css" />
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/common.css" type="text/css" />

  <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.easing.1.3.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.bxSlider.min.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.fitvids.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="js/welcome.js"></script>
  <script type="text/vbscript" src="scripts/shortcut.vbs" ></script>
  <script type="text/vbscript">call CheckShortcut()</script> <!--was at the bottom between html and body-->
  
  <script language="javascript">
   /*var avaHeight = window.screen.availHeight; //maximizes to screen size. need to be able to be able to move content with screen for this to work
   var avaWidth = window.screen.availWidth;
   window.moveTo(0, 0);
   window.resizeTo(avaWidth,avaHeight);*/
   window.resizeTo(1366,750);
   window.moveTo(60,60);
  </script>
  
  <hta:application 
   id="Welcome" 
   applicationname="Windows 10 Welcome Wizard" 
   caption="yes"
   scroll="no"
   showintaskbar="yes"
   singleinstance="yes"
   sysmenu="yes"
   windowstate="normal"
   border="thin"
   icon="favicon.ico"
  />
 </head>
 <body scroll="no">
  <div class="container_12">
   <div class="wrapper">
    <div class="grid_3 nav"> <!--Left navigation bar for jumping to all of the panels-->
     <ul>
      <li><img src="img/star.png" width="15" height="15" class="left" /><a href="#">Welcome</a></li><li>
      <img src="img/star.png" width="15" height="15" class="left" /><a href="#"    >Familiarize yourself with Windows 10</a><br><img src="img/RightDropDown.png" width="20" height="20" class="left" /></li>
      <li><a href="#" class="startSubSpace"           >Start Menu</a></li>
      <li><a href="#" class="tilesSubSpace"           >Tiles</a></li>
      <li><a href="#" class="subSpace"            >Action Center</a></li>
      <li><a href="#" class="subSpace"            >Settings</a></li>
      <li><a href="#" class="subSpace"            >Microsoft Edge</a></li>
      <li><img src="img/star.png" width="15" height="15" class="left" /><a href="#">CKCentral</a></li>
      <li><img src="img/star.png" width="15" height="15" class="left" /><a href="#">Chatham-Kent Apps</a></li>
      <li><img src="img/star.png" width="15" height="15" class="left" /><a href="#">Office 2013</a></li>
      <li><img src="img/star.png" width="15" height="15" class="left" /><a href="#">Skype for Business</a></li>
      <li><img src="img/star.png" width="15" height="15" class="left" /><a href="#">Email Signature</a></li>
      <li><img src="img/star.png" width="15" height="15" class="left" /><a href="#">Internet Options</a></li>
      <li><img src="img/star.png" width="15" height="15" class="left" /><a href="#">Internet Favourites</a></li>
      <li><img src="img/star.png" width="15" height="15" class="left" /><a href="#">Network Drive Info</a></li>
      <li><img src="img/star.png" width="15" height="15" class="left" /><a href="#">Direct Access</a></li>
      <li><img src="img/star.png" width="15" height="15" class="left" /><a href="#">Find & Add Printers</a></li>
      <li><img src="img/star.png" width="15" height="15" class="left" /><a href="#">Default Printer</a></li>
      <li><img src="img/star.png" width="15" height="15" class="left" /><a href="#">Software Centre</a></li>
      <li><img src="img/star.png" width="15" height="15" class="left" /><a href="#">Training</a></li>
      <li><img src="img/star.png" width="15" height="15" class="left" /><a href="#">IT Service Desk</a></li>
     </ul> 
    </div>
    <div class="grid_9 main">
     <div class="slider">
      <div class= "Welcome"> <!--Welcome Panel-->
       <h1></h1>
       <p>
       </p>
       <ul>
        <li><strong><a href="#" class="startLinks" id="WinTen1"></a></strong><br><br></li>
        <li><strong><a href="#" class="startLinks" id="Edge6"></a></strong><br><br></li>
        <li><strong><a href="#" class="startLinks" id="Skype10"></a></strong><br><br></li>
        <li><strong><a href="#" class="startLinks" id="FindPrinter16"></a></strong><br><br></li>
        <li><strong><a href="#" class="startLinks" id="Email11"></a></strong></li>
       </ul>
       <p>
       </p>
       <img src="img/CKLogo.jpg" width="462" height="86" class="center" />
      </div>
      <div class = "Familiarize"><!--Familiarize Windows Panel-->
       <h1></h1>
       <p>
        <img src="img/Windows10.jpg" width="300" height="200" class="left" />
       </p>
       <ul>
        <li><strong><a href="#" class="startLinks" id="Start2"></a></strong><br><br></li>
        <li><strong><a href="#" class="startLinks" id="Tiles3"></a></strong><br><br></li>
        <li><strong><a href="#" class="startLinks" id="Action4"></a></strong><br><br></li>
        <li><strong><a href="#" class="startLinks" id="Settings5"></a></strong><br><br></li>
        <li><strong><a href="#" class="startLinks" id="Edge6"></a></strong></li>
       </ul>
       <p></p>
      </div> 
      <div class = "StartMenu" id = "StartMenu"> <!--Start Menu Panel-->
       <h1></h1>
       <p>
       </p>
       <embed src="videos/StartTestSmall.mp4" width="660" height="400" type="video/mp4" autoplay="0" />
      </div>
      <div class = "Tiles" id = "Tiles"> <!--Tiles Panel-->
       <h1></h1>
       <p>       
       </p>
       <img src="img/StartTilesSmall.png" width="559" height="386" class="left" />
      </div>
      <div class = "ActionCenter" id = "ActionCenter"> <!--Action Center Panel-->
       <h1></h1>
       <img src="img/ActionCenter.png" width="220" height="450" class="left" />
       <img src="img/ActionCenterChatBuggle.png" width="216" height="70" class="right" />
       <p>       
       </p>
      </div>
      <div class = "Settings" id = "Settings"> <!--Settings Panel-->
       <h1></h1>
       <p>
        <img src="img/WindowsSettings.png" width="630" height="250" />
       </p>
      </div>
      <div class = "Microsoft-Edge" id = "Microsoft-Edge"> <!--Microsoft Edge Panel-->
       <h1></h1>
       <p>
        <img src="img/EdgeLogo.jpg" width="162" height="176" class="left" />
       </p>
       <ul>
        <li><br><br></li>
        <li></li>
       </ul>
       <p>
        <br><br>
        <small><i></i></small>
       </p>
      </div>
      <div class = "CKCentral"> <!--CKCentral Panel-->
       <h1></h1>
       <img src="img/CKCentralNav.png" width="717" height="76" class="left" />           
       <p>
       </p> 
       <img src="img/CKCentralWinter.png" width="548" height="230"  />
      </div>
      <div class = "Chatham-Kent Apps"> <!--Chatham-Kent Apps Panel-->
       <h1></h1>
       <p>
        <img src="img/ChathamKentApps.png" class="left" />
        <img src="img/CKAppsFolder.png" width="436" height="310" class="right" />
       </p>
      </div>
      <div class = "Office2013"> <!--Office 2013 Panel-->
       <h1></h1>
       <p></p>
       <ul>
        <li><br><br></li>
        <li><br><br></li>
        <li><br></li>
       </ul>
       <img src="img/Officeicons.png" width="400" height="255" class="left" /> 
       <p>
        <strong><a href="httranet.cthPage/ome.apx" target="_blank"></a>.</strong>
       </p>
      </div>
      <div class = "SkypeforBusiness"> <!--Skype for Business Panel-->
       <h1></h1>
       <p>
        
        <img src="img/SkypeforBusinessHome.png" width="253" height="454" class="left" />
        <br><br>
       </p>
       <ul>
        <li><strong></strong><br><br></li>
        <li><strong></strong><br><br></li>
        <li><strong></strong><br><br></li>
        <li><strong></strong></li>
       </ul>
       <img src="img/SkypeforBusinessContact.png" width="172" height="169" class="right" />
       <p>
        <strong>
        <a href="https://ckinditePages/Lync.aspx" target="_blank"></a></strong>.
       </p>
      </div>
      <div class = "EmailSignature"> <!--Email Signature-->
       <h1></h1>
       <p>
       </p>
       <ul>
        <li></li>
        <li></li>
       </ul>
       <p>
        <a href="https://ckintra/howto/Pag0877.aspx" target="_blank"></a>.
       </p>
       <img src="img/FileOutlook.png" width="300" height="175" class="left" />
       <img src="img/inFileOutlook.png" width="300" height="310" class="left" />
      </div>
      <div class = "InternetOptions"> <!--Internet Options-->
       <h1></h1>
       <p>
        <br><br>
        <br><br>
       </p>
       <img src="img/BatmanRobinBatgirl.png" width="428" height="320" class="left"/> <!--(500, 375)-->
       <p>
       </p>
       <ul>
        <li></li>
       </ul>
      </div>
      <div class = "Internet Favourites"> <!--Internet Favourites Panel-->
       <img src="img/IEfav.png" width="190" height="180" class="right" /><h1></h1>
       <p>
       </p>
       <h1><br></h1>
       <p>
        <img src="img/EdgeFavourites.png" width="260" height="140" class="right" />
       </p>
       <br><br>
       <h1></h1>
       <p>
        <img src="img/googlefav.png" width="209" height="213" class="right" />
       </p>
      </div>
      <div class = "Network_Drive_Info"> <!--Network Drive Info-->
       <h1></h1>
       <ul>
        <li><strong></strong><br><br></li>
        <li><strong></strong><br><br></li>
        <li><strong></strong><br><br></li>
        <li><strong></strong><br><br></li>
        <li><strong></strong><br><br></li>
        <li><strong></strong><br><br></li>
        <li><strong></strong></li>
       </ul>
       <img src="img/NetworkDrives.png" width="622" height="121" class="left" />
       <img src="img/C-Drive.png" id="CDrive" width="232" height="70" class="right" />       
      </div>
      <div class = "DirectAccess"> <!--Network Drive Info-->
       <h1></h1>
       <p>
       </p>
       <img src="img/MicrosoftDirectAccess.png" width="465" height="86" class="left" />
      </div>
      <div class = "FindAddPrinters"> <!--Find & Add Printers-->
       <h1></h1> <!--this only works in the network tell this somewhere-->
       <p> 
        <br><br>
        <strong>
         <a href="https://ckintraowto/Pages/18153.aspx" target="_blank"></a>.
        </strong>
        <br><br>
        <br><br>
        <a href="mailto:itskent.ca"></a> 
       </p>
       <img src="img/printer picture.png" class="center" />
      </div>
      <div class = "Default Printer"> <!--Default Printer Panel-->
       <h1></h1>
       <p>
        <strong></strong>
       </p>
       <ul>
        <li><br><br></li>
        <li><br><br></li>
        <li></li>
       </ul>
       <img src="img/default printer.png" width="489" height="341" class="left" />
      </div>
      <div class = "Software Centre"> <!--Software Centre Panel-->
       <h1></h1>
       <img src="img/SoftwareCenterOptionButtons.png" width="570" height="106" />
       <p>  
        <br>
        <br><br>
        <br><br> 
        <br><br> 
        <br><br>
       </p>
      </div>
      <div class = "Training"> <!--Training-->
       <img src="img/TrainingLogo.png" class="center" />
       <p>
        <a href="https://ckintra/Office/SitePages/Home.aspx"></a>.
        <br><br>
        <a href="https://www.micrdows/features"></a>
        <br><br>
        <a href="maihnt.ca"></a> 
       </p>
       <img src="img/classroomwithcomputers.jpg" class="center" />
      </div>
      <div class = "ITServiceDesk"> <!--IT Service Desk Panel-->
       <img src="img/ServiceDeskLogo.png" class="center" />
       <p>
        <strong><br></strong>
        <br><br>
        <br>
        <a href="https://ckintranek/howto/"></a>
        <br><br>
        <a href="mailto:itseram-ca"></a>
        <br>
        <br><br>
       </p>
      </div>
     </div> <!--/slider-->
    </div> <!--/main-->
    <label class="donotshow"><input id="checkboxDONTSHOW" name="checkboxDONTSHOW" type="checkbox"  onclick="toggle()" /></label>
    <div class="controls">
     <a class="exit" href="#"></a>
     <a class="prev" href="#"></a>
     <a class="next" href="#"></a>
    </div> <!--/Controls-->
   </div> <!--/Wrapper-->
  </div> <!--/Container_12-->
 </body> 
</html>
```

EDIT 2: I found a workaround but it is not ideal. I link the video through an 'a' tag and the video loads through the link every time. However, person viewing the page will have to click on the link if they want to see the video.

```
<a href="videos/StartTestSmall.mp4" width="660" height="400" id="StartMenuVideo">Start Menu Video</a>
```

Comment: What is the issue exactly? Is the video file disappearing and you're re-adding it or is it not being recognized? Those would be two different issues. One would be a system issue whereas the other would be a coding issue.

Comment: the file itself is not disappearing, the player that is supposed to be in one of the HTA slides sometimes doesn't appear and the only way to make it appear is to close the HTA and relaunch until it appears at another random time.

Comment: Did you want to load an embedded video in VLC with HTA ?

Comment: Can you edit your question and provide us the hole source code of this HTA ? May be there are some tags not closed ? or something else ? and what is your OS and the version of Internet Explorer ?

Comment: Get rid of this scroll="no" on body tag and change it to scroll="yes" and of course on hta tag

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have tried this HTA file on another computer and it works perfectly. it seems that the many failed attempts that I tried where being brought in from my cache.
Thank you for everyone's help

Answer (score 1):

You can try this example that required **[the VLC application](http://www.videolan.org/vlc/)** must be installed !

```
<html>
<head>
<title>VLC_SO_MOVIE : Tranporteur 3 by Hackoo</title>
<HTA:APPLICATION
  APPLICATIONNAME="VLC_SO_MOVIE"
  ID="VLC_SO_MOVIE"
  ICON="Winver.exe"
  VERSION="1.0"/>
</head>
<BODY>
<center>
<object width=100% height=100%
 classid = "clsid:9BE31822-FDAD-461B-AD51-BE1D1C159921"  
  codebase = "http://download.videolan.org/pub/videolan/vlc/last/win32/axvlc.cab" 
  id = "vlc" 
  name = "vlc" 
  class = "vlcPlayer" 
  events = "True" > 
    <param  name = "src" value = "http://urlz.fr/2XWM" /> 
    <param  name = "ShowDisplay"  value = "True"  /> 
    <param  name = "AutoLoop"  value = "False"  /> 
    <param  name = "AutoPlay"  value = "True"  /> 
</object>
</center>
</BODY>
</HTML>
```

**Edit :** This embedded video is working for me on windows 7 with internet explorer version 11 :

```
<html>
<head>
<title>Embedded video : The Hobbit 3 : The Battle of the Five Armies by Hackoo</title>
<HTA:APPLICATION
  APPLICATIONNAME="Embedded video"
  ID="Embedded video"
  ICON="Winver.exe"
  WINDOWSTATE="maximize"
  VERSION="1.0"/>
<style>
body {
color:white;
background-color:lightblue;
background-image:url(http://lagenerationz.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/01/the-hobbit-3.jpg);
background-repeat:repeat;
background-size: 100%;
}
</style>
<script type="text/vbscript">
Sub Reload()
    window.location.reload(True)
End Sub
</script>
</head>
<BODY>
<center>
<br><hr>
<embed src="http://urlz.fr/2XVB" width=50% height=50% type="video/mp4" autoplay="0"/>
<br><hr>
<img src="http://www.icone-png.com/png/23/22961.png" Title="Reload Application video" alt="Reload Application video" onclick="Reload()" style="cursor:hand">
</center>
</BODY>
</HTML>
```

Comment: the only issue with this is the application is going to be sent to multiple computers that probably don't have this application.

Comment: hmmm, I'm on windows 10 as this hta is a windows 10 tutorial, and IE11. Thank you for sticking with me Hackoo